# How to filter Django queryset by non field values

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I need to query a model by their local time.

```
send_reminder_query = PersonModel.objects.filter('Is after 7pm thier localtime')
```

The person will have a zipcode field and I have a function to get the timezone by their zipcode. I'd also be willing to write a migration script to populate the timezone on the Person model but I still don't see how to make the query.

`send_reminder_query = PersonModel.objects.filter(tzinfo='...', ?)`

Comment: show your `PersonModel` model.

Comment: How do you know their "local time"? are you storing more information about  them?

Comment: I only know their zipcode but from that I can get their timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by pre processing the data to store the person's timezone. Then using `pytz` I do this.

```
from django.utils import timezone 
import pytz


valid_timezones = []
for tz in list_of_timezones:
    local_time =  now().astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz))
    if 19 < local_time.hour < 20:
        valid_timezones.append(tz)

reminders = Person.objects.filter(timezone__in=valid_timezones)
```